# How to modifiy a file inside docker Image

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-machine

I pulled a docker image from https://github.com/snowflakedb/SnowAlert.

But after pulling the Image, I don't see any containers running. I used
`docker container ls`  command and it returned no containers.
Now due to some usecase I want to modify a file inside this docker image.
What is the correct way to do it?

Thanks

Comment: That repository has two Dockerfiles; you should be able to modify one of those and then `docker build` a new image with your changes.  For some changes (especially injecting config files) there could be a simpler path, but in general you can't modify a built image at all.

Answer (score 2):

Here is what resolved my issue.
After pulling the repository from the github I ran below commands

```
sudo docker images
```

This will display the names of existing images. Now copy the Image name in which you need to do the modification.

```
sudo docker run -it <copied_image_name> bash
```

This will open a bash where all the files are residing. Do the modification where ever it is required then type `exit`

Copy the container Id from below command

```
sudo docker ps -a
```

Now we need to commit the changes into new Image using below command

```
sudo docker commit <container_id> <new_image_name>
```

Thats all
Now do `sudo docker images` this will display the newly created image with the modified content.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Don't confuse image with container: https://phoenixnap.com/kb/docker-image-vs-container.

You need to "up" image to create appropriate container for it: https://docs.docker.com/get-started/part2/#run-your-image-as-a-container

If you want to inspect/edit any container use command (it like ssh to container's server):

```
docker exec -it CONTAINER_ID bash
```

To get all docker containers and find their IDs use command:

```
docker ps -a
```

Comment: `docker container ls -a` should also work, ls display the currently running container by default

Comment: @DDKV587 You are right, it also must output containers, but don't miss first part of my answer: You need to "up" image to create appropriate container at first.

Comment: Remember that any changes you make in a `docker exec` shell will be lost as soon as the container exits.